# Fastest way to split a large data frame into subframes by row

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, split, data.table

I have a large `data.table` that looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e5
p <- 100
dt <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p))
```

I want to split it into a list of `N` frames by row (this will need to account for the case when `N` does not divide `n`). Here's my current implementation:

```
split_dt <- function(dt, N)
  split(dt, f= c(rep(seq(N), each = n %/% N), rep(N, n %% N)) )
```

Here are results from a `microbenchmark` test:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( split_dt(dt, N = 10) )

Unit: milliseconds
        expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
split_dt(dt, N) 150.114 154.2513 159.7832 157.1903 162.7404 187.2896   100
```

Couple of questions on this:

1. Is there a substantially faster way to implement this operation?
2. Does my implementation take advantage of `data.table`'s internal optimization methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I think this does take advantage of data.table, assuming you are using the development version (which announces in item 21 that a split method for data.tables has been added https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md )

Comment: A good percentage of the time someone wants to do this, it turns out they simply need to use `by` instead. Why do you need to split your data?

Comment: I am interested in splitting the matrix for its own sake. I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do this.